# Is it possible to say 'start living for future'

Tags: articles, determiners

I write a poem.
How it's better to say:

> Because today is your chance
>   To forget about your past and start living for future.

Or

> Because today is your chance
>   To forget about your past and start to live for the future.

Or maybe some other variant.

Answer (score 3):

> Because today is your chance
>   To forget about **your/the** past and start to live for **your/the** future.

since its poetry.
I would use the same *the* or *your* in both places of the second line.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, *future* does need *the*; so, the second one is better.

Comment: I agree with your sentiments, but I also think "start living" is better than "start to live," so I'd combine them: _today is your chance
to forget about your past and start living for the future._

Answer (score 0):

```
Because today is your chance
To forget about your past 
And focus on the future.
```

Being unaware of what came before and what is to follow, it might be a little presumptuous of me... but you have two lines of seven-syllable free verse that flow quite well.

The third line is a *suggested edit*.

As to your question: *...start living for future* is not proper English. *Future* must be modified in some way.

This could also stand alone as a haiku:

```
Today is your chance
To forget about the past.
Live for the future.
```